# How to move/copy all files directory from local machine to s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to move/copy the particular extension file(.xlsx) move to my s3 bucket.

I am using below command for this.

```
cmd= 'aws s3 cp myfolder/*.xlsx s3://mybucket/myfolder --recursive'

where:
**myfolder** is my local system directory where the file is present

**s3://mybucket/myfolder** : folder location where i am placing all the .xlsx file in s3.
```

But when I am running this command using python

```
os.system(cmd)

Getting Error : 255
```

can anyone suggest me any change or any other way to achieve the goal?

Note: I already configured my system cmd whit my s3 key and all commands are working fine also.

UPDATE:

```
cmd = '$aws s3 cp myfolder/*.xlsx s3://mybucket/myfolder --recursive'
```

```
getting error:1 on interactive python.
```

Comment: What happens if you run Python interactively, and run those two lines? When I do it, it comes back with an error that my `myfolder` does not exist (which is correct). See what yours says.

Comment: is there a reason you are using python just to execute the aws command? If you run that command directly, does it work?

Comment: You don't need `$` at the beginning.

Comment: If your question is resolved, please accept the answer so it gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in a command's path arguments.** Use `--exclude` and `--include` filters.

`aws s3 cp myfolder s3://mybucket/myfolder/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.xlsx"`

**The order of the parameters matters.**

Note that running help command `aws s3 help`, brings same command reference as linked below.
From [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters):

> Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in
> a command's path arguments. However, most commands have `--exclude "<value>"`
> and `--include "<value>"` parameters that can achieve the
> desired result. These parameters perform pattern matching to either
> exclude or include a particular file or object.  The following pattern
> symbols are supported.
>
> - "*": Matches everything
> - "?": Matches any single character
> - "[sequence]": Matches any character in "sequence"
> - "[!sequence]": Matches any character not in "sequence"

> **Note that, by default, all files are included.** This means that
> providing only an `--include` filter will not change what files are
> transferred. `--include` will only re-include files that have been
> excluded from an `--exclude` filter. If you only want to upload files
> with a particular extension, you need to first exclude all files, then
> re-include the files with the particular extension.